# resetting the Windows 7 display without logging off

Tags: windows-7, display

When I work from home, I remote desktop into my machine at work.  Often when I do this, when I get to work and want to use the machine, the display is screwed up (see picture below) and I have to reboot or at least log off to fix it.

I don't want to log off or reboot as it takes forever.  I was trying to fix it some other way.  I went to the display, changed the resolution, and then changed it back hoping that would fix it but it did not.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried restarting explorer.exe in the task manager?

Comment: I will try it..